# How to list items in alphabetical order with a heading and if no match is found display a message

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, foreach, alphabetical

My plan of action was:

1. Loop through an array of the alphabet
2. While inside of that loop, print the current letter
3. While inside of that loop cycle through a list of city objects stored in an array.
4. Check and see if the first letter of the $city->city_name property matches the current letter in the loop. If it matches, print it.
5. If there are no matches, print a message saying so.

This is all I can get it to display:

### A

There are no results to display.

### B

There are no results to display.

### C

City

There are no results to display.

### D

There are no results to display.

### E

City

There are no results to display.

As you can see, the error displays even if there is a match. I cannot seem to figure out where the flaw in my logic is and I've searched through every question on the topic. Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Code:

```
<?php
function printValues($cities, $county) 
{
    $str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $letters = str_split($str);
    $lettersMatched = FALSE;

    foreach ($letters as $letter) 
    {
        echo "<h5 class=\"letter\">".$letter."</h5><hr>";

        foreach ($cities as $city) 
        {
            if(substr($city->city_name, 0, 1) == $letter) 
            {
                $lettersMatched = TRUE;
                $result = $city->city_name;
                echo "<p><a href=\"".site_url("/listings/county/".$county."/city/".$result)."\">".$result."</a></p>";
                $lettersMatched = FALSE;
            }
        } 
        if (!$lettersMatched) 
        {
            echo "<p>There are no results to display.</p>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're resetting $lettersMatched to false inside the if statement. Try this:

```
<?php
function printValues($cities, $county) 
{
    $str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $letters = str_split($str);
    //$lettersMatched = FALSE;

    foreach ($letters as $letter) 
    {
        echo "<h5 class=\"letter\">".$letter."</h5><hr>";
        $lettersMatched = FALSE;

        foreach ($cities as $city) 
        {
            if(substr($city->city_name, 0, 1) == $letter) 
            {
                $lettersMatched = TRUE;
                $result = $city->city_name;
                echo "<p><a href=\"".site_url("/listings/county/".$county."/city/".$result)."\">".$result."</a></p>";
                // $lettersMatched = FALSE;
            }
        } 
        if (!$lettersMatched) 
        {
            echo "<p>There are no results to display.</p>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Jim , the reason I was setting it to false is because I _thought_ that I needed to in order to display the no results message. When I do that, it displays only the matches under the letters and no error message. For example: A|city, city B| C| D|city, city E| city F| G| and so on. Edit: It seems that the first error displays and none of he rest do. So A|city, city B| No results C| D|city, city E| city F| G| and so on.

Comment: Hi Ellenbrook: I made an edit to my answer: you should reset the $lettersMatched at the start of each new letter (i.e., at the top of the first foreach loop.

Comment: Jim, this worked. Thank you so much for the help! I was racking my brain all night. It seems that I was resetting it in the wrong area. Your way makes so much sense and I can't believe I didn't think of it before!

Comment: Neat @Jim resetting the variable before the loop is even more elegant than my solution

Answer (score 0):

```
$matches = false;
foreach(range('A', 'Z') AS $letter)
{
    echo $letter . '<hr>';

    foreach( $cities AS $city )
    {
        if( strtoupper(substr($city->city_name, 0, 1)) ===  $letter)
        {
            $matches = true;
            echo "<p>" . $city->city_name . "</p>";
        }
    }

    if(!$matches)
        echo "<p>No matches here</p>";

    $matches = false;

}
```

What you did was to set the matches to false right after you set it to true in the inner loop. So when your code reaches the condition outside the loop it will **always** be `false`.

What I did was to set the matches to false **after** the condition, so it will be checked again for each new letter.